# how to insert images in web page from a firefox addon?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I have a firefox add-on I am writing, which injects javascript code into page when the page title changes.

I am adding some javascript content that builds html. I want to be able to view images inside the html and I want the images to be saved in the /content directory of my add-on. Is it possible?

Basically I think it's should be something like this:

```
  <img src="chrome://my_addon_id/content/images/download.jpg" />
```

However, it's not working.

A few tips of how to do that will be very helpful.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you need to make your addon [contentaccessible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/chrome_registration#contentaccessible).

Comment: Hi thanks for the lead. But can you kindly please explain, is it a parameter in the manifest or a change in the firefox about:config? - and how do i link to the image in the chrome? - thanks.

Comment: @aviv It's a parameter in the manifest. It means that you can inject images that use chrome URLs for your package. Without that manifest parameter the image gets blocked as a security error.

Comment: still no luck. I added the contentaccessible=true to the manifest and i still can't access the images. Can you please give me some more information about accessing the data?

Comment: I take it the URL chrome://my_addon_id/content/images/download.jpg works correctly if you open it directly? Also, it needs to be `contentaccessible=yes`.